# Keras fit generator not use GPU in Tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a code implemented with `Keras` and I am using the `fit_generator` because the size of the data is pretty big.

Here is my code:

```
model = ad.kerasCNN() 

model.fit_generator(
    ad.data_generator(X_TRAIN_metadata, Y_TRAIN_metadata, batch_size), 
    steps_per_epoch, 
    epochs=maxEpoch, 
    verbose=1, 
    callbacks=[history, early_stopping], 
    validation_data=ad.data_generator(X_DEV_metadata, Y_DEV_metadata, batch_size), 
    validation_steps=steps_per_epoch_dev, 
    class_weight=None, 
    max_queue_size=10, 
    workers=1, 
    use_multiprocessing=False, 
    initial_epoch=0
)
```

When I run this code with a **GPU** I don't face any issue during the training phase, the GPU being used at between 70 - 80%.

But when the code goes into the validation, the GPU is not used.
This implies that the validation time is 23 times longer than the training phase.

Is it a normal behavior of keras / tensorflow?

What can I do to use the GPU in validation time?

Comment: pls format your code - it is impossible to read it as inline

Comment: The code is formated. This is a only call to a fit_generator from keras such as I am using.

Comment: Inline formatting is not meant for such long snippets - code block should be used instead. We are just trying to help get your question answered, you are always free to *not* listen..

Comment: Well, now is with a code block.